# How can I send Firebase notifications using cloud functions on firebase database data change?

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, firebase-cloud-messaging, google-cloud-functions

I'm trying to create a cloud function that sends notifications when the firebase database value is changed.
Below is my firebase database snapshot... I want to send a notification when the value `liveurl` document changes

```
livestream
    |_ 
      liveurl: "https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Z8agqyGIaD8"
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a prime example of a use case for Cloud Functions and Cloud Messaging. In fact, a similar scenario is covered in the [What can I do with Cloud Functions?](https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/use-cases) documentation under the [Notify users when something interesting happens](https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/use-cases#notify_users_when_something_interesting_happens) section:

> [image: notify example]
>
> 1. The function triggers on writes to the Realtime Database path where followers are stored.
> 2. The function composes a message to send via FCM.
> 3. FCM sends the notification message to the user's device.

There is also a [FCM Notifications quickstart sample available on GitHub](https://github.com/firebase/functions-samples/tree/master/fcm-notifications) for this.

As a quick example, you could write a Cloud Function to do this, something like:

```
const functions = require('firebase-functions');
const admin = require('firebase-admin');
admin.initializeApp();

exports.liveUrlChange = functions.database.ref('/livestream/liveurl').onWrite((event) => {
    // Exit if data is deleted.
    if (!change.after.exists()) return null;

    // Grab the current value of what was written to the Realtime Database.
    const value = change.after.val();
    console.log('The liveurl value is now', value);

    // Build the messaging notification, sending to the 'all' topic.
    var message = {
        notification: {
            title: 'Database change',
            body: 'The liveurl value has changed to ' + value
        },
        topic: 'liveurl_changed'
    };

    // Send the message.
    return admin.messaging().send(message)
        .then((message) => {
            console.log('Successfully sent message:', message);
        })
        .catch((error) => {
            console.error('Error sending message:', error);
        });
});
```

This is a [Cloud Functions](https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/) method that will react to changes to the `/livestream/liveurl` node in your database and use Cloud Messaging to [send a message to a topic](https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging/admin/send-messages#send_to_a_topic) (namely `liveurl_changed`).

In order for this to work, you'll need to:

1. [Deploy this function to Cloud Functions](https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/get-started)
2. [Setup Cloud Messaging in your app](https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging/android/client)
3. [Subscribe the client app to the `liveurl_changed` topic](https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging/android/topic-messaging#subscribe_the_client_app_to_a_topic)

Answer (score 2):

Try this cloud function :

```
exports.sendNotification = functions.database.ref('/livestream/{liveurl}').onUpdate((data, context) => {

const liveurl = context.params.liveurl;

//getting the instance of the target user. this instance object will contain the device token of the target user
return admin.database().ref(`/apps/${app_id}/users/${sender_id}/instances`).once('value').then(function(instancesIdAsObj) {

    const tokens = Object.keys(instancesIdAsObj.val());

    const payload = {
        notification: {
        title: sender_fullname,
        body: text,
        icon : "ic_notification_small",
        sound : "default",
        click_action: "NEW_MESSAGE",
        "content_available": "true",
        badge : "1"
    },

        data: {
            liveurlString: liveurl,
        }
    };

    return admin.messaging().sendToDevice(tokens, payload).then(function (response) {
        console.log("Push notification for message "+ JSON.stringify(message) + " with payload "+ JSON.stringify(payload) +" sent with response ",  JSON.stringify(response));

                return error;
            }
        });

    })
    .catch(function (error) {
        console.log("Error sending message:", error);
        return 0;
    });

});
```

});